# How to type special symbol on Cloud Shell with Mac EU keyboard?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-shell, google-cloud-console

Considering this context:

- MacBook
- European Keyboard (or non US keyboard)
- Google Cloud Shell (on Google Cloud Console)

How to type special symbols like `|` (pipe), `\`(backslash) ?

Normally, on MacOS, we can use `ALT + SHIFT + L` for `|` (pipe), and `ALT + SHIFT + /` for `\` (backslash).

But on Google Cloud Shell, it's not working. 
How can we do ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the solution:

- Open Cloud Shell
- Click on settings icon at left side (gearing icon)
- Select Terminal Preferences > Keyboard > Alt-Gr key
- Choose Left + Alt or Right + Alt

You're done.

Now, `ALT + SHIFT + L` will work like a charm on your favorite Google Cloud Shell.

Answer (score 2):

**Update 02/2021:**

There is a new setting for tat.

- Open Cloud Shell
- Click on settings icon (gearing)
- Enable checkbox for `Alt is meta`

[image: Setting]

That solved it for me.